# Pivot_longer() with multiple new columns

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyr, reshape

I have a question about `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.

Lets say I start with an imaginary dataframe.
Imagine people were asked two Questions about two Genres. SQ1_2 would be the second question about the first genre.

```
set.seed(1234)
genres <- c("Crime", "Horror", "Love", "Sci-Fi", NA)
wide <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:10,
  Genre_1 = sample(genres, 10, replace = TRUE),
  Genre_2 = sample(genres, 10, replace = TRUE),
  SQ1_1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
  SQ1_2 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
  SQ2_1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
  SQ2_2 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

| ID | Genre_1 | Genre_2 | SQ1_1 | SQ1_2 | SQ2_1 | SQ2_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sci-Fi | Sci-Fi | 3 | 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Horror | Sci-Fi | 4 | 1 | 3 | 5 |

I strive to achieve an end result like this:

| ID | time | Genre | SQ1 | SQ2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Genre_1 | Sci-Fi | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | Genre_2 | Sci-Fi | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | Genre_1 | Horror | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | Genre_2 | Sci-Fi | 3 | 5 |

I used to do this task the following way:

```
long1 <- wide |> tidyr::pivot_longer(col = starts_with("Genre"),
                              names_to = "time",
                              values_to = "genre")
long2 <- wide |> tidyr::pivot_longer(col = c(SQ1_1, SQ2_1),
                              names_to = "time",
                              values_to = "SQ1")
long3 <- wide |> tidyr::pivot_longer(col = c(SQ1_2, SQ2_2),
                              names_to = "time",
                              values_to = "SQ2")
long <- long1 |> 
  dplyr::select(ID, time:genre) |>
  dplyr::mutate(SQ1 = long2$SQ1,
         SQ2 = long3$SQ2)
```

I was just curious if there is any way to create multiple new columns from different variables with one call of `pivot_longer()` (or any other function for that matter).

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the naming rule consistent for those columns you want to pivot into longer format:

- The *j*-th genre = `Genre_j`
- The *i*-th question about the *j*-th genre = `SQi_j`

Therefore, the initial name `SQ1_2` should be renamed as `SQ2_1` and vice versa. Then stack `Genre`, `SQ1`, `SQ2` respectively:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

wide %>%
  rename_with(~ sub('(\\d)_(\\d)', '\\2_\\1', .x), starts_with('SQ')) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1,
               names_to = c(".value", "Time"),
               names_sep = '_')

# # A tibble: 20 × 5
#       ID Time  Genre    SQ1   SQ2
#    <int> <chr> <chr>  <int> <int>
#  1     1 1     Sci-Fi     3     5
#  2     1 2     Sci-Fi     2     2
#  3     2 1     Horror     4     1
#  4     2 2     Sci-Fi     3     5
```